# FCM in chrome extension - getToken() empty

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a chrome extension which should be able to receive FCM messages. To get my FCM token, I use the following code

```
messaging.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
    messaging.getToken().then(function(current_token) {
        if(current_token) {
            //update user token
            console.log('token', current_token);
        } else {
            // you don't have permission to show notifications
            // detect whether they are blocked or not, then show your custom UI
        }
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // retrieving token failed, analyze the error
        console.error('retrieving token failed, analyze the error', err);
    });
}
```

But the problem is the `permission` I get are of type undefined, and then I don't get any result from `getToken()`, no empty token, no error, nothing.

Comment: I think there is an open issue related to yours. Here is the link: [FCM doesn't work for chrome extensions](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/241). You might want to join the discussion there to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so thanks to @Mr.Rebot comment I figured out that this is most likely a chrome bug and the workaround is to manually whitelist extension in [Chrome Notification Settings](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3220216?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Your extension link looks like `chrome-extension://<extension-id>/`.

Comment: For people in the future, make sure you add "notifications" as a permission in your `manifest.json`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to do in order to get the token:

1. Create empty `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in project root and include it as a background scripts in `manifest.json`. For example I did this:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/firebase-app.js",
        "js/firebase-messaging.js",
        "firebase-messaging-sw.js",
        "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
}
```

2. Now add `"notifications"` permission in manifest.json. Mine looks like:

```
"permissions": [
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "notifications"
]
```

Now `messaging.getToken()` (in `background.js`) will work fine without even using `messaging.requestPermission()`.